# How to implement a clean Custom Object Initializer for a Matrix class

Tags: c#, object-initializers, collection-initializer

I have a custom `Matrix` class that I would like to implement a custom object initializer similar to what a double[,] can use but can not seem to figure out how to implement it.

Ideally I would like to have it look like this

```
var m1 = new Matrix
        {
            { 1.0, 3.0, 5.0 },
            { 7.0, 1.0, 5.0 }
        };
```

as of now I have a regular constructor with a signature of

```
public Matrix(double[,] inputArray){...}
```

that accepts a call like this

```
var m1 = new Matrix(new double[,]
        {
            { 1.0, 3.0, 5.0 },
            { 7.0, 1.0, 5.0 }
        });
```

and an object intializer that accepts the following using by inheriting the `IEnumerable<double[]>` interface and implementing an public void `Add(double[] doubleVector)` method

```
var m2 = new Matrix
        {
            new [] { 1.0, 3.0, 5.0 },                
            new [] { 7.0, 1.0, 5.0 }
        };
```

when I try using the object intializer I would like to I get a compiler error of not having an overload for `Add` that takes X number of arguments where X is the number of columns I am trying to create (i.e. in my provided examples 3).

How can I set up my class to take in an argument like I provided?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

define `Add` method with `params` keyword and ignore ending element in array, which is longer than matrix width

```
public void Add(params double[] doubleVector)
{
   // code
}
```

if array is shorter, default elements are left (`0`)

```
// sample
var M = new Matrix()
{
    { 1.2, 1.0 },
    { 1.2, 1.0, 3.2, 3.4}
};
```

Comment: Learned something today.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: wouldn't the class would need to implement IEnumerable to be able to use this?

Comment: but matrix should have equal length and width

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary You can't assure that in C# besides with run-time checks anyway

Comment: @DerekVanCuyk I stated in the original question that I had already inherited IEnumerable